# Canopy Height Model of LiDAR data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, model, canopy-height-model

I have a DTM and DSM files. I want to develop a Canopy Height Model (CHM) in QGIS.  Is it possible?

Comment: is it more complicated than subtracting DTM from DSM?

Comment: how to do that could you eloborate please i am a learner?

Comment: @Arun I am also computing the height of canopy from a DSM and DTM file. I am very new to this area, can you tell me how I can access the height information after I have created the DSM-DTM layer ?
Much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the raster calculator plugin you would subtract one file from the other: DSM - DTM. This will give you a new file that would be just the canopy.

Answer (score 1):

The canopy model in QGIS is obtained by subtracting DTM from DSM which gives the height of the tree (Kim et al., 2010).

Comment: It really depends on you naming of the surface model. I have seen people use DSM and DTM interchangeably. The process is subtract two tasters, the bare earth model from the raster that had the canopy. This will give you just the canopy.

Comment: ya but when we subract DSM from DTM it gives negative values particularly the height what is the meaning for that?

Comment: Then switch the order of the input rasters