# Expression into the raster calculator to invert DEM

Tags: dem, lidar, watershed, basin

I've made a DEM from first pass LiDAR data which I want to invert and run watershed segmentation and basin delineation over in order to hopefully extract tree canopy outlines and heights - I'm newish to GIS.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Multiply your raster by -1 or subtract it from 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canopy Height Model of LiDAR data in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/canopy-height-model-of-lidar-data-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks - I think I need to both - subtract the DSM from the DTM but also run the watershed segmentation and basin delineation over the inverted DSM to try and extract canopy outlines and approximate trunk location - (Edson 2011) - though it's an urban condition so it may just fail due to the buildings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would subtact the last pass and the first pass elevation if you want the height. You could also possibly add a constant (e.g. 100) in order to have positive values but this is more an esthetic consideration.

by the way, DEM is used for ground elevation, in your case it is a DSM.

in the raster calculator (assuming you are using QGIS)

```
dem@1 - dsm@1
```

replace dem@1 with any constant value if you don't have a DEM at the same resolution as your DSM.

Comment: Thanks - I do have both at the same resolution so will try this and then just use the inverted DSM to hopefully get canopy outlines and high points...